# Docker zookeeper forgets about created kafka topics

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

Giving the following docker-compose yml, I keep running into the problem that the zookeeper forgets about created topics. I can stop and restart the zookeeper container, and also the kafka container. The problems arises when I run docker-compose down.

After a restart I see kafka reopening correctly with the topics in the /data directory, but after calling the describe topic function I get an empty list, as if it does not exist.

What am I doing wrong?
Command I run to create the topics:

```
unset JMX_PORT
kafka-topics.sh --create --topic users --replication-factor 1 --partitions 2 --zookeeper zk:2181
```

to check if there are two partitions created:

```
kafka-topics.sh --topic users  --describe --zookeeper=zk:2181
```

This is the docker-compose file, but it seems ok to me ...

```
version: '2'
volumes:
  kafka-data:
    external: true
  kafka-zk:
    external: true
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: zookeeper:3.4
    volumes:
    - kafka-zk:/data
  kafka:
    image: ches/kafka
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: '127.0.0.1'
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: '0'
      ZOOKEEPER_CONNECTION_STRING: zk:2181
    ports:
    - "9092:9092"
    volumes:
    - kafka-data:/data
    links:
    - zookeeper:zk
```

Comment: BTW: I am trying this on a windows 10 Pro with Docker 17.06.0-ce-win19

Answer (score 0):

Found it, I forgot to volume mount the datalog.
Added the following: `- kafka-zk-datalog:/datalog` noww it works.